# discord.js find returning undefined

Tags: discord.js, sendmessage

I am trying to add a small function to my bot so that when the bot is online people are notified.

I have done the following:

```
//BOT connexion actions
client.on("ready", function () {
    console.log("BOT connected");
    client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'ID').send("text");
});
```

I even tried to use the const I had as all the bot messages are returned in a specific channel yet it still does not work

```
const channel01 = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "ID");
...
client.channel01.send("text");
```

Of course, ID is the specific channel ID.

The error I get in short is:`(node:22000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

I am not sure what is wrong here as the .send is handled properly on command input.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if you already have the channel ID.

```js
client.channels.fetch('ID').then(chan => {
    chan.send('The bot is now online!');
});
```

As to why your code wasn't working, you're tying to check the name "general", etc with an ID, that's the equivalent to.
`Does "12383929184" equal "general"?`

Answer (score 0):

here's a little solution to your problem:

In your first function, you're trying to find a channel by name, although it seems as if you're trying to look for an id instead.
If you're trying to get the channel by it's name:

```
const channelObject = client.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'channel name');
```

Else, if you're looking to find it by the ID, you could use:

```
const channelObject = client.channels.fetch('Channel ID');
```

From there, we can simply type:

```
channelObject.send('text')
```

and we'll get a little notification when the bot is online!

Comment: Thank you for that! Now it tells me that: "(node:22916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: channelObject.send is not a function"
How to drive me crazy. It seems to also mess with my token as when I have those two lines I have an extra error stating "(node:9376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordjsError: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client." and it is gone as soon as I comment them out...